# Spring transaction multiple datasource

Tags: spring

I am having two datasource one for oracle and other for postgresql and both are used in same business method . How i can make this bussiness method transactional using spring @transaction

Business method

```
@Transactional 
public int getData(){

oracleDao.func1();
postgreDao.func2();
}
```

In config i have

```
<bean id="transactionManagerPostGres" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
      </bean>   
  <bean id="transactionManagerOracle" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryOracle"/>
 </bean>
```

Answer (score 5):

You're going to need the support of a proper JavaEE container for this, one that supports two-phase-commit and XA transactions. The Oracle and Postgres JDBC drivers both support XA transactions, so that's OK.

The container exposes this to Spring via the JTA API, and Spring uses that using `JtaTransactionManager`. Your application doesn't have to change, it just treats it like a normal transaction.

How you go about setting this up depends entirely on your JavaEE container, each one has a different way of doing it.

Comment: I am going to deploy the application  on servicemix.

Comment: @prabha: In that case, you need to dive into the ServiceMix docs, and find out if it has XA JTA support. If not, you need to find another container that does, or find something that integrates with what you have. That's a question specific to that container, and is independent of Spring.

Comment: Can I make @transaction annotation to use different transactionManager in the same method?

Comment: @prabha: Yes, using `<tx:annotation-driven transactionManager="..."/>` - see docs at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations

Comment: Note that the `JtaTransactionManager` replaces both of your existing `JpaTransactionManagers`.

Comment: when i using @Transactional("transactionManagerOracle") the code did not compile

Comment: @prabha: That's not what the documentation says. Read the link I gave you.

Comment: i tried using   <qualifier value="oracle"/> also and then in transaction @Transaction("oracle") still it does not work

Comment: And in eclispe i can see all attrripute of @transaction except the value

Comment: Thanks all ..I can set the value property now

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a [two-phase commit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol)? That's a tough problem and depends on the databases and the drivers you use.

Comment: i want to set business method as transaction either full commit or rollback.